# ssh "permissions are too open"

Tags: permissions, ssh

I get the following error from ssh:

```
Permissions 0777 for '/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is recommended that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
```

What permissions should I give to the id_rsa file?

Comment: Thanks for asking the quesiton. A better experience would be for the one who wrote this error message to suggest a few valid configurations (such as 600 or 400 as suggested below). Programmers not writing sufficiently complete error messages that are helpful have been torturing all of us for years!

Comment: FWIW, this is related to `StrictModes` being enabled on the `sshd` server, from the [man](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd_config(5)) page: "StrictModes Specifies whether sshd(8) should check file modes and ownership of the user's files and home directory before accepting login." - you could disable this however not suggested.

Comment: Instead of `It is recommended` my os shows `It is required`. Maybe my os is newer (2020) and that`s why.

Comment: Also applies to other setups, such as even `Permissions 640 ... are too open` and other OSes such as [Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unix) as well as [Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux)

Comment: Unfortunately, the question cannot be edited any more. `Title cannot contain "ssh "permissions are too open" error"` It tells me "Please provide a title that summarizes your question. For assistance, see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" - which I want to suggest and share here and now.

Comment: Had the same error. In my case I just incorrectly configured .ssh/config and used public key:  `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. So when changed to `IdentityFile  ~/.ssh/id_rsa` everything worked well.

Comment: Remove (`-`) read permissions for Others And Group: `chmod go-r id_rsa`. `g` for `group`, `o` for `others`, `r` for `read`. No more strange codes, meaning is the king.

Answer (score 5227, accepted):

The keys need to be read-writable only by you:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Alternatively, the keys can be only readable by you (this also blocks your write access):

```
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

`600` appears to be better in most cases, because you don't need to change file permissions later to edit it. (See the comments for more nuances)

The relevant portion from the manpage (`man ssh`)

> ```
>  ~/.ssh/id_rsa
>          Contains the private key for authentication.  These files contain sensitive 
>          data and should be readable by the user but not
>          accessible by others (read/write/execute).  ssh will simply ignore a private 
>          key file if it is              
>          accessible by others.  It is possible to specify a
>          passphrase when generating the key which will be used to encrypt the sensitive 
>          part of this file using 3DES.
>
>  ~/.ssh/identity.pub
>  ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
>  ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub
>  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
>          Contains the public key for authentication.  These files are not sensitive and 
>          can (but need not) be readable by anyone.
> ```

Comment: 400 is too low as that makes it non-writable by your own user. 600 is actually recommended as it allows owner read-write not just read.

Comment: I discovered today there are times when 400 is relevant. Suppose you have an authorized_keys file that has the [no-pty et al](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html) features set. If the file is writeable, the user can actually overwrite the authorized_keys file and gain interactive shell access! Something to keep in mind, though surely not the general case for most folks.

Comment: ugh... I'm moving the file... I don't even want it where it is, I'm just setting a password. Can I tell ssh-keygen that I'm smarter than it, and that I don't care about the permissions just this once?

Comment: AWS actually recommends permission 400 on their website. That's what I did on OS X and it worked.

Comment: This definitely works and is more secure. The only downside is you then have to change it to 600 to edit. For id_rsa, and id_rsa.pub I doubt that matters because you rarely ever will edit those files, but for authorized_keys, it could be annoying. Best to understand the tradeoffs and configure each system appropriately.

Comment: I suppose it also depends on how often you're editing them. Many people set it and forget it, thus 400 would be more secure from others and your own actions; modifying to 600 when necessary.  If it's part of your workflow and your ssh-savy, then maybe it would be more of a hindrance to keep changing permissions.

Comment: **IMPORTANT** : For me, I was unable to change permissions of `id_rsa` inside `.ssh` folder, so I changed the permission of it on my desktop then copied it to `.ssh` folder with this code after `cd desktop` use `cp -frp id_rsa ~/.ssh` then add it `ssh-add -K id_rsa`

Comment: @theonlygusti Have a look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55481/14572); this helped me today. The perms on the www-data users home directory needed to be modified; subtle issue IMO.

Comment: `chmod 400` didn't work for me, despite no warning or error, the file permissions were just not changed - as if the command did nothing. Figured it must be cuz my private key was inside a folder shared between a VM and his host machine (i.e., chmod be like "hey, it's publicly accessible so no new file permissions for you!"). So I moved the key to `~/.ssh/private_key`, chmoded it over in this folder instead and now everything works.

Comment: How to change the permissions under **Windows** folder? I tried to change it to 600 but failed. If I change it to 600 under Ubuntu folder, it was successful. However, if I copied the file with 600 to the windows folder, its permissions came back to 777.

Comment: If you are **using a VM in Windows and experiencing problems**, your file is probably in a **shared folder** between the VM and Windows. Try copying the file to a folder that only the VM has access to, _then_ change permissions.

Comment: I was on WSL, had to move the .pem file to the mounted linux root before I can run chmod on it. `mv clidemo.pem ~/.ssh/clidemo.pem` adn then `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/clidemo.pem` worked.

Comment: @GeorgeMylonas From Cygwin, even a 400 command is giving this kind of issues for AWS

Comment: Wrote up this article to outline the whole process
https://www.thedevnote.xyz/note/how-to-move-your-ssh-generated-keys-to-a-new-laptop

Comment: I think you can do `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -vvv';`, then run the clone command to get more details on what seems to be an unrelated warning (if the pull is working).

Comment: After trying either, I still get `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`

Answer (score 126):

Using Cygwin in Windows 8.1, there is a command need to be run:

```
chgrp Users ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then the solution posted here can be applied, 400 or 600 is OK.

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

[Reference here](http://vineetgupta.com/blog/cygwin-permissions-bug-on-windows-8)

Comment: locale-dependent. I had to run "chgrp Użytkownicy ~/.ssh/id_rsa"  since "Users" errored no such group.

Comment: I had to do this as well. My cygwin directory was in the default location (`C:\cygwin64`) so it probably inherited the permissions. Strange that this didn't happen on other laptops I've owned.

Comment: @Marcos I've added an answer that works regardless of locale: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28647713/67013

Comment: Windows 10. Used the second command only. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Note that for installations in alternative languages the 'Users' group has alternative identifiers.

Comment: I use sudo `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa`. Then, run ssl -L xxxx id_rsa. it asks me that the authenticity of host 'ci-smartface.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com (13.94.213.109)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is yyyy. Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?. I enter 'yes', same error is exist  WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!  .

Answer (score 89):

I've got the error in my windows 10 so I set permission as the following and it works.

[image: Permission for id_rsa of windows 10]

In details, remove other users/groups until it has only 'SYSTEM' and 'Administrators'. Then add your windows login into it with Read permission only.

Note the `id_rsa` file is under the `c:\users\<username>` folder.

Comment: I have the same problem on Win-10. Based on your explanation, not clear what did you actually allowed and denied - I have "users' and 'authenticated users' and Not 'specific user" as options + System and Administrators. Besides I could not figure out cygwin - to install or use.(?)

Comment: **for Win10 need move your key to user's home** - this worked perfectly. I was trying giving full path to key and messing with the permissions - nothing worked.

Comment: @Sam-T if you cannot see your name in list, you can add by press ```Edit...``` then press ```Add...``` then type your name in the text box ```"Enter the object names to select"``` then press ```Check Names``` button (and press ```OK``` and another ```OK```) then your name should be listed in the ```Security``` tab

Comment: I probably can add the name specifically - per your instructions. But my main question was - **what exact permissions to Deny and Allow for all**.  Meanwhile as mentioned I was able to solve the problem by simply adding the `.pem` to the `myuser directory`

Answer (score 56):

**Windows 10 ssh into Ubuntu EC2 “permissions are too open” error on AWS**

I had this issue trying to ssh into an Ubuntu EC2 instance using the .pem file from AWS.

In windows this worked when I put this key in a folder created under the .ssh folder

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\.ssh\private_key
```

To change permission settings in Windows 10 :

> File Settings > Security > Advanced
>
> Disable inheritance
>
> Convert Inherited Permissions Into Explicit Permissions
>
> Remove all the permission entries except for Administrators

Could then connect securely.

Comment: moving the private key under .ssh was enough for me (and chmod 600)

Answer (score 53):

The locale-independent solution that works on Windows 8.1 is:

```
chgrp 545 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

GID 545 is a [special ID](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html) that always refers to the 'Users' group, even if you locale uses a different word for Users.

Answer (score 44):

AFAIK the values are:

- `700` for the hidden directory `.ssh` where key files are located
- `600`  for the keyfile `id_rsa`

Answer (score 42):

0600 is what mine is set at (and it's working)

Answer (score 35):

I have got a similar issue when i was trying to login to remote ftp server using public keys.
To solve this issue I have done the following process:

- First find the location of the public keys, because when you try to login to ftp, this public key is used.
- Alternatively, you can create a key and set that key's permissions to `600`.
- Make sure you are in the correct location and perform this command:

```
chmod 600 id_rsa
```

Comment: This is worked for macos m1

Answer (score 31):

I got success with `sudo`

```
sudo chmod 400 pem-file.pem
sudo ssh -i pem-file.pem username@X.X.X.X
```

Comment: the only things that worked for me

Comment: sudo is the only thing that worked out of all

Comment: Using windows wsl and this worked!

Comment: Same it work for me in windows 11. Thanks

Comment: You saved the day for me thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 29):

On Windows 10, cygwin's `chmod` and `chgrp` weren't enough for me. I had to

- right click on the file
- -> Properties
- -> Security (tab)
- and remove all users and groups except for my active user.

Comment: This is only solution that is working :) Thanks you saved my time

Comment: I found that, after doing this, I could do ssh from normal Windows command prompt as well. No need to use Cygwin. Great!

Answer (score 24):

provide 400 permission,
execute below command

```
chmod 400 /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

There is one exception to the `0x00` permissions requirement on a key. If the key is owned by root and group-owned by a group with users in it, then it can be `0440` and any user in that group can use the key.

I believe this will work with any permissions in the set `0xx0` but I haven't tested every combination with every version. I have tried `0660` with `5.3p1-84` on *CentOS 6*, and the group not the primary group of the user but a secondary group, and it works fine.

This would typically not be done for someone's personal key, but for a key used for automation, in a situation where you don't want the application to be able to mess with the key.

Similar rules apply to the `.ssh` directory restrictions.

Answer (score 18):

For windows users Only.
Goto **file property** --> security --> advanced

1. Disable inheritance property
2. Convert Inherited Permissions Into Explicit Permissions.
3. Remove all the permission entries except the Administrators.
   [image]

[image]

Answer (score 15):

This is what worked for me (on mac)

```
sudo chmod 600 path_to_your_key.pem
```

then :

```
ssh -i path_to_your_key user@server_ip
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 10):

**for Windows :**

Strange, but UI tweaks, described here before **did not helped me**.

But this solved the issue :

1. Open PowerShell under admin rights
2. Go to directory with your keys (using cd command)
3. Enter commands one by one

:

```
$path = ".\{your private key file name}" //for example "myKey"
```

Then remove your explicit permissions by typing:

```
icacls.exe $path /reset
```

Then assign to current user read-permission:

```
icacls.exe $path /GRANT:R "$($env:USERNAME):(R)"
```

Then remove inheritance:

```
icacls.exe $path /inheritance:r
```

Hope, will help someone

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Simply use the following:

```
sudo chmod 600 [Location of Private Key]/[Name of Private Key]
sudo chmod 700 [Location of Folder Containing Private Key]/[Name of Folder Conataining Private Key]
sudo ssh -v -i key.pem ubuntu@instance.re-region-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 9):

#### In case you are using **WSL on windows**

The most **simple answer** is to just type: `sudo ssh -i keyfile.pem <user>@ip`

without changing the file permissions.
The [reason](https://superuser.com/a/1323647) why this happens?
[Another resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#are-files-in-the-linux-drive-different-from-the-mounted-windows-drive)

> You can't modify the permissions of files on Windows's filesystem
> using chmod on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. You'll have to copy the
> private key to your WSL home directory (~) and do it there.

---

On the other hand, `sudo` should never be utilized with ssh. The reason why issuing with `sudo` works is that it's now likely being executed as root, and this is not the correct way to do this and is a massive security risk, as Allowing for anything other the 600/400 permissions defeats the purpose of utilizing an SSH key, compromising the security of the key.

The **best way** to do that is by copying the file to `$HOME/.ssh`:

`cp keyfile.pem ~/.ssh`

Doing `sudo chmod 400 keyfile.pem` to it.

Then `ssh -i keyfile.pem <user>@ip`.

Comment: Bingo (on Windows 10 WSL)! It's nice to chmod Windows files from WSL Linux as folk tried here, but clearly still problematical and shifting sands over time. Moving the .pem private key to Linux where running SSH from makes total sense, and it works - and without any chmod or chgrp. Thank you (phew, BTW!).

Answer (score 6):

For me (using the Ubuntu Subsystem for Windows) the error message changed to:

```
 Permissions 0555 for 'key.pem' are too open
```

after using chmod 400.
It turns out that using root as a default user was the reason.

Change this using the cmd:

```
 ubuntu config --default-user your_username
```

Answer (score 6):

I got same issue after migration from another mac. 
And it blocked to connect github by my key.

I reset permission as below and it works well now.

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh     # (drwx------)
cd ~/.ssh            
chmod 644 *.pub      # (-rw-r--r--)
chmod 600 id_rsa     # (-rw-------)
```

Comment: I got the same error with these: ```Permissions 0644 for '.../...pub' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.```

Answer (score 6):

As people have said, in Windows, I just dropped my `.pem` file in `C:\Users\[user]\.ssh\` and that solved it.  Although you can do `chmod` and other command line options from a bash or powershell prompt that didn't work.  I didn't change rsa or anything else.  Then when running the connection you have to put the path to the pem file in the `.ssh` folder:

```
ssh -i "C:\Users\[user]\.ssh\ubuntukp01.pem" ubuntu@ec[ipaddress].us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 5):

what worked for me

> chgrp Users FOLDER
>
> chmod 600 FOLDER

Comment: chgrp: grupo inválido: «Users»

Comment: I tried but keep throwing out 'invalid group `:Users'', why? using Windows 10, powershell

Comment: @user1418225 'Users' is locale-dependent, try the answer of thehouse at https://stackoverflow.com/a/28647713/11154841.

Answer (score 5):

```
700  folder
644  id_rsa.pub
```

this works for me.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the accepted answer, if you have done all the suggested means, and you are using "wsl" ubuntu on windows, you can append "sudo" to your ssh command e.g

`sudo ssh -i xxx.pem xxxx@xxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 4):

I keep all my own certificates and keys in one directory, and this works for tools like PuTTY, but I got this `too open` error message from the scp command. I discovered that Windows already maintains a `C:\users\ACCOUNTNAME\.ssh` folder having the proper access rights for storing SSH keys. So long as you keep the contents backed up (Windows sometimes deletes it during updates), or create your own folder for ssh keys in your user folder, this will work fine, as only you and the administrators have access to that parent folder.

Be very careful about changing access rights on Windows folders. I did this, and once a day Windows is scanning, reading, and writing all the files on my `C:` drive, a process that slows the computer for many minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting message here.
Operating Systems are smart enough to deny remote connections if your private key is too open. It understands the risk where permissions for id_rsa is wide open (read, is editable by anyone).

{One may change your lock first and then open it with the keys he already has}

```
cd ~/.ssh
chmod 400 id_rsa
```

While working on the multiple servers (non-production), most of us feel need to connect remote server with ssh. A good idea is to have a piece of application level code (may be java using jsch) to create ssh trusts between servers. This way connection will be password-less. Incase, perl is installed - one may use net ssh module too.

Answer (score 3):

The other trick is to do that on the downloads folder.
After you download the private key from AWS EC2 instance, the file will be in this folder,then simply type the command

```
ssh-keygen -y -f myprivateKey.pem > mypublicKey.pub
```

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this issue on WSL on Windows while connecting to AWS instance. My issue got resolved by switching to classic Command prompt. You can try switching to a different terminal interface and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the issue was a whitespace too much.

```sh
ssh -i mykey.pem  ubuntu@instace.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

but

```sh
ssh -i mykey.pem ubuntu@instace.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

worked fine. The problem is that the whitespace is taken as part of the username.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Windows 10 and trying to connect to EC2 instance via SSH. Rather than using Cygwin for Windows, try using Git Bash. After doing `chmod 400` for key I am able to SSH into the EC2 instance, but the same is not working for me from Cygwin. Windows treats the .pem file as coming from internet and blocks it, even disabling inheritance doesn't work.

I converted the file to .ppk format and it's working fine from PuTTY also, but it's not working from Cygwin.

Comment: Problems using ssh in Cygwin can be due to ssh not being installed in Cygwin. The default path in Cygwin includes the Windows version of ssh, so if you type "ssh ..." in Cygwin you might assume that the ssh command is one that (should go) with Cygwin. But if ssh is not installed in Cygwin, typing "ssh ..." invokes the Windows version instead.

Answer (score 2):

I tried `600` level of permission for my private key and it worked for me.

```
chmod 600 privateKey 
[dev]$ ssh -i privateKey user@ip
```

---

On the other hand,

```
chmod 755 privateKey 
[dev]$ ssh -i privateKey user@ip
```

was giving below issue:

```
Permissions 0755 for 'privateKey' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "privateKey": bad permissions
```

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 10 this is what I've found works for me:

1. Move your key to the Linux file system:
   `mv ~/.ssh /home/{username}`
2. Set the permission on that key:
   `chmod 700 /home/{username}/.ssh/id_rsa`
3. Create a symbolic link to the key:
   `ln -s /home/{username}/.ssh ~/.ssh`

This happens if you have set your home directory (`~`) to be stored in Windows instead of Linux (under `/mnt/` vs `/home/`).

Answer (score 1):

I have came across with this error while I was playing with Ansible. I have changed the permissions of the private key to **600** in order to solve this problem. And it worked!

```
chmod 600 .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
```

Answer (score 1):

PuTTY can do the work on windows 10. It generates a public key using a private key as input.

1. [Download PuTTY](https://www.putty.org/)
2. Install PuTTY.  Two applications come upon the installation: putty config, putty key gen
3. Launch puttyGen
4. Click load and select a private key file. Please note, you need to rename your private key file with `.ppk` extension, *e.g.* `private-key.ppk`

[image: Screenshot of an empty PuTTY Key Generator]

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. This is a very old question, about OSX, not Windows, that already has an accepted and highly upvoted answer.

Answer (score 0):

for Win10 need move your key to user's home dir
for linuxlike os you need to `chmod` to `700` like or `600` etc.

Comment: **for Win10 need move your key to user's home** - this worked perfectly. I was trying giving full path to key and messing with the permissions - did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to connect from the Ubuntu app in Windows 10 and got the error above.
It could be resolved without any permission changes by running `sudo su` in the Ubuntu console prior to the actual command

Answer (score -2):

I am using VPC on EC2 and was getting the same error messages. I noticed I was using the public DNS. I changed that to the private DNS and vola!! it worked...

Comment: Amazon recommends chmod 400, and using the public DNS. Refer to documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html