# ssh-add error: "Permissions are too open"

Tags: ssh, file-permissions, ssh-keys

When trying to load my keys I get this error

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh
Permissions 0755 for '/home/starkers/.ssh' are too open.
```

Note that the permissions are too open for the `.ssh` directory, not an actual key.

Modifying the ownership doesn't change anything:

```
chmod 755 ~/.ssh
ssh-add ~/.ssh
Permissions 0755 for '/home/starkers/.ssh' are too open.
```

The thing is, I need to write to this directory when I create new keys, so what's it on about?

Comment: Just a small tip, `chmod` doesn't modify the ownership (that's `chown`).

Comment: Oh, fair enough! Still it says that 0755 is too lenient. Don't know what it's on about frankly. Get none of this rubbish on my local machine. I need to write and read to it, end of.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ssh "permisssions are too open" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270734/ssh-permisssions-are-too-open-error)

Comment: It's not. Why I said `Note that the permissions are too open for the .ssh directory, not an actual key.`

Comment: Its the same thing; your directory has the wrong permissions. It should be `700`; I'm not sure why you have `755` there.

Comment: Would you revoke that close please I went to the trouble of pointing out the difference.

Comment: If it's 600, I can't write to the directory when generating a new key. Is the idea to lock down the directory once I've generated a key? I haven't experienced this on my local machine, but that does make sense.

Comment: This answer has been answered, refer to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270734/ssh-permissions-are-too-open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270734/ssh-permissions-are-too-open)

Answer (score 19):

Your `.ssh` directory should have permissions `0700`. Not 0600 (too strict) or 0755 (too permissive). Do:

`chmod -R 700 ~/.ssh`

Use `-R` to recursively change permissions for all files in there.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody should be able to get at your keys except you, not even to read them or discover their names. That's basic sensible security and it means no permissions whatsoever for group or world.

First *you* should own the directory. Then, you should be using something like 600 or 700 (preferably the latter, see below).

From the `ssh` man-page (but with my italics):

> **~/.ssh/**
> This directory is the default location for all user-specific configuration and authentication information.  There is no general requirement to keep the entire contents of this directory secret, but the recommended permissions are *read/write/execute for the user, and not accessible by others.*