# Permission denied (publickey) but public key exists locally and remotely

Tags: linux, ubuntu, github, ssh, public-key

I have the following error when I tried to push:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists
```

I know what it means. However, `id_rsa.pub` does exist locally and it's copied to bitbucker as well, they are both identical. The repository exists also.

What could the cause?

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: do you have a bitbucket entry in your ~/.ssh/config?

Comment: @m79lkm, I don't have this path. However, I was able to push to this repository successfully on my previous system. On this system I have the same ~/.ssh directory with the same content because I copied it from the previous system (Mint).

Comment: If you used `cp` in moving the files, you are especially likely to have garbled up file permissions on the new system. `rsync` is best suited to move files and preserve permissions.

Comment: @GuyHughes, what permissions should be there? On my new system all of the them have root root permissions.

Comment: @GuyHughes, you're genius! Where did you get this idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Public Key issues

1. Check that you're putting in the correct remote repository path (i.e. `git@github.com:username/reponame`).
2. Debug the connection with `ssh git@somehostname.com -T -vv` to get verbose mode. 
   Check the output. It will tell you what's going on. If you're still stuck, post it here and we can have a look.
3. `ssh` will often complain if your private key **or** its parent directories leading to the private key have [higher permissions set than they ought to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270734/ssh-permisssions-are-too-open-error).

   1. The key itself should be set with `chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, and the `~/.ssh` directory to 0700 at most.
   2. The `~` and `~/..` (parent directory, often `/home` on Linux and `/Users` on Mac OS X) should be set to 744 at most.
   3. Also check that the group and user permissions are set correctly on the key and its parent directories:

      > ```
      > $ id -un && id -ug   # check output of this command before using!
      > username
      > groupname
      > $ chown --recursive $(id -un):$(id -gn) ~
      > ```

      This will reset all permissions on your home directory so your current user and group own all files. This may not be what you want. See `man chown`.
4. You may also want to check the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the remote host if you're still having trouble. Its permissions are also a point of failure.

---

## Repairing OSX directory permissions

@AlexanderSupertramp, I said the permissions should be `744` **'at most,'** yes, referring to the requirements for SSH only. But I did not suggest that you should chmod the `/home` directory to that number. Each operating system has its own requirements for directory permissions, and I could only provide generic instructions since you didn't provide much information about your system. In any case, I am terribly sorry that my answer was not clear.

It is possible that your mac is failing to boot because `744` is too liberal. But I cannot be sure.  To resolve this you may want to pay a visit to the Genius Bar at an Apple Store or contact an authorized repair technician. You may also be able to fix the directory permissions automatically using built-in tools as follow:

1. Boot into single-user mode by pressing `Command+S` at the same time as the power button to turn on your mac, as explained in [this article](http://www.cultofmac.com/240390/use-single-user-mode-to-solve-wonky-mac-os-x-issues-os-x-tips/).
2. Launch the OSX Disk Utility from the menu bar, and then use the repair permissions tool as described in this [Apple KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1452)

Comment: what's the somehostname in `ssh git@somehostname.com -T -vv`?

Comment: It could be anything depending on where you want to connect to.  If you are using github.com, it would be `ssh git@github.com`, whereas the first part before the `@` symbol is the ssh 'username' (`git`) but that is different from your username on github.com. If you are using bitbucket.org, it would be `git@bitbucket.org`.

Comment: your second advice says `The ~ and ~/.. (parent directory, often /home on Linux and /Users on Mac OS X) should be set to 744 at most.`. So I did `sudo chmod 744 ~/..` and I can't boot my mac anymore.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, I've updated my answer. I never suggested you should set your `/home` directory permissions to 744. I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hi.I have been running into the exact same problem but on Windows OS.It works for few days after I add the SSH key and I get the same error after that.Any suggestions ?