# ssh key file unprotected private key file error every time after reboot

Tags: git, capistrano

I have a weird problem where every time after I reboot my Mac 
I get the following error while trying to deploy using capistrano

> Permissions 0644 for '/Users/guy/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' are too open

I don't remember how I fixed this last time. I just remember it was annoying and also happened a reboot to the computer.

my permission for the id_rsa file are 600
and for the id_rsa.pub are 644

if I run `chmod 600 id_rsa`

then it will ask for a password while deploying with capistrano. 
a password which I don't know...

any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that all the parent folders of your ssh keys are not writable for group or other.

For instance: 755 or stricter (not 775 anywhere)

That is for:

- `/Users`
- `/Users/guy`
- `/Users/guy/.ssh`

The question "[Password dialog appears when SSH private key permissions are set to 0600](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/18458)" includes a lot of good advices, including one that the OP followed:

> When I had an `id_rsa` but not a corresponding `id_rsa.pub`, Mac OS X kept popping up the dialog and remember password in my keychain did nothing.

```
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -y -f id_rsa > id_rsa.pub
```

> generated the appropriate public key file for me.

So re-generating can help.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! checked all those folders. all are 755 :( so it still doesn't work

Comment: @guyschaller do you mean do you still see "Permissions are too open"? Or do you only see now the password being asked?

Comment: still same error of permissions are too open. I don't get it last time this happened after a reboot it just suddenly started working again.. haha

Comment: @guyschaller but now, even after a reboot, it doesn't work, does it? Did you used recently a different ssh url?

Comment: nope didn't change anything. I use capistrano with its deploy script. same server and same git repo. thanks for the help!

Comment: @guyschaller does the capistrano process uses the same account, and has the same `HOME`?

Comment: what do you mean same account? I haven't touched anything that has to do with deployment or capistrano. for at least a few weeks.

Comment: @guyschaller ok. Is your provate key owned by the right group? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/22674741/6309)

Comment: @guyschaller check also http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/26252 and http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/33210

Answer (score 1):

ended up just creating a new ssh key with a passphrase, because no other solution worked

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Comment: Indeed, that was one of the links I mentioned in the comment: I pout it in my answer for more visibility.