# vagrant rsync protocol mismatch

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, chef-solo, joyent, vagrant-gatling-rsync

I am facing following Rsync issue when i say vagrant up --provider=joyent ... after node creation its giving following error... when i observer rsync versions on both machines .., its same.. i dont know how to troubleshoot this ..

```
==> default: Couldn't find Cheffile at ./Cheffile.
==> default: Rsyncing folder: /home/system/Documents/tobe/dsrv195/ => /vagrant
There was an error when attemping to rsync a share folder.
Please inspect the error message below for more info.

Host path: /home/system/Documents/tobe/dsrv195/
Guest path: /vagrant
Error: Warning: Identity file  not accessible: No such file or directory.
protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
(see the rsync man page for an explanation)
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(174) [sender=3.1.0]

root@system-desktop:/home/system/Documents/tobe/dsrv195#
```

Anyone please help

Comment: It's saying the Identity File isn't accessible. Have you checked your id_rsa/id_dsa file to make sure it's in place and looks reasonable?

Comment: root@system-desktop:/home/system/Documents/tobe/dsrv195# cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa 
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 

key is coming

but i didnt understand why its facing difficulty to access id_rsa and  do i required to change any permssions for id_rsa

Comment: @NoahGibbs can you please check

Comment: id_rsa absolutely needs specific permissions. Here's an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270734/ssh-permissions-are-too-open-error

Answer (score 1):

yes its fixed .. after copying `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys` to root

Comment: Well, since the asker answered his own question, the answer must be the right one !