# vagrant rsync : Enter passphrase for key

Tags: ssh, cygwin, vagrant, rsync

when I run vagrant rsync, the prompt keep me asking 'Enter passphrase for key' and then the vagrant password for the user.
All of my collegue that are working with the same vagrant configuration dont' insert any password after the vagrant rsyn command.

It looks like it can't create the /home/Administrator/.ssh folder, but I run the command as normal user.

The output of vagrant ssh-config is

```
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile 
C:/Users/USERNAME/projects/fisch/VagrantVM/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

In attachement the output of vagrant rsync --debug
Thank you all

[image]

After some hours spent investingating about it seems that the problem is related to cygwin:

```
    C:\Users\USERNAME\projects\fisch\VagrantVM>ssh -p2222 vagrant@localhost
     Could not create directory '/home/Administrator/.ssh'.
     The authenticity of host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
     RSA key fingerprint is dd:8f:cf:c0:7a:b9:6b:b5:2e:78:70:4b:8f:e3:bf:47.
     Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
     Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts     (/home/Administrator/.ssh/known_hosts).
```

And again the error related to the wrong path, I'm expecting **/home/USERNAME/.ssh**

Comment: can you output the result of command `vagrant ssh-config`

Comment: sure, now it's in question

Comment: possible duplicate of [ssh "permissions are too open" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270734/ssh-permissions-are-too-open-error). Take a look at the second answer of the linked question; it's the same situation (Windows/Cygwin) and error message.

Comment: No it's related to the wrong path the cygwin is chosing