# Connect over SSH using a .pem file

Tags: ssh, pem

I would like to know how to connect over SSH using a `.pem` file to any server.

Currently I'm executing the following command:

```
ssh user@mydomain.example
```

What option should I use?

Answer (score 325, accepted):

Use the `-i` option:

```
ssh -i mykey.pem myusername@mydomain.example
```

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9270753/113848), this file needs to have correct permissions set. The [ssh man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) says:

> SSH will simply ignore a private key file if it is accessible by others.

You can change the permissions with this command:

```
chmod go= mykey.pem
```

That is, set permissions for **g**roup and **o**thers **equal** to the empty list of permissions.

---

If you're going to connect to this server with this key many times in the future, it might be worth configuring it once and for all. Open the file `~/.ssh/config` (create it if it doesn't exist), and add:

```
Host mydomain.example
    IdentityFile /path/to/mykey.pem
    User myusername
```

Now you can just type `ssh mydomain.example`, and it will use the specified key file and user name.  See the [ssh_config man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) for more details.

Comment: I just to point out that if you aren't root, you should chmod the .pem file and enable the read permission for your user.

Comment: This only addresses the client side of the equation. For setting up the server, you'll need to copy your public key into the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file. You can do this from your local machine by: "ssh-copy-id -i ~/mykey.pub user@mydomain.com".

Comment: If port is different - 
ssh -i mykey.pem user@mydomain.com -p 2222

Answer (score 79):

```
chmod 400 mykey.pem

ssh -i mykey.pem user@mydomain.example
```

Will connect you over SSH using a `.pem` file to any server.

Comment: "chmod 400" solved this issue:
Permissions 0777 for 'some_file.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.

Answer (score 27):

For AWS if the user is ubuntu use the following to connect to remote server.

```
chmod 400 mykey.pem

ssh -i mykey.pem ubuntu@your-ip
```

Answer (score 18):

To connect from Terminal to AWS AMI:

```
chmod 400 mykey.pem

ssh -i mykey.pem ec2-user@mydomain.example
```

Answer (score 7):

You can connect to a AWS ec-2 instance using the following commands.

```
chmod 400 mykey.pem

ssh -i mykey.pem username@your-ip
```

by default the machine name usually be like ubuntu since usually ubuntu machine is used as a server so the following command will work in that case.

```
ssh -i mykey.pem ubuntu@your-ip
```

Answer (score 5):

If you still got error messages like:

> Received disconnect from `34.219.50.0` port 22:2: Too many authentication failures. Disconnected from `34.219.50.0` port 22

1. **Edit your SSH config** located at `~/.ssh/config` and add new record at the end

```
Host mydomain.example
   User ubuntu
   IdentityFile /home/you/path-to-pem/key.pem
   IdentitiesOnly yes
```

2. Call short command: `ssh mydomain.example`

Answer (score 0):

what resolved it for me was to run: `sudo chown $USER: {.pem_file}`

Answer (score 0):

*$ chmod 400* /path/example.pem

enter correct path after /

*$ ssh -i* /path/example.pem username@ip

enter correct path,enter the username and the ip

[reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lightsail/latest/userguide/amazon-lightsail-ssh-using-terminal.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).