# OpenSSH Windows - AWS "eb ssh" results in "Warning: Unprotected Key File!"

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, openssh

I'm trying to connect to my AWS Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance using OpenSSH, which I have downloaded because I'm using Windows.

When running `eb ssh` I am greeted with the message: "Warning: Unprotected Key File! Permissions 0444 for '(key name)' are too open."

This is frustrating because I went into the .ssh folder and used `chmod` to set it to 0400, not 0444.

The key I am using was generated using the ssh tool, and I uploaded it to AWS and set it as the key pair so I know it's OpenSSH at fault here, rather than AWS.

I am then prompted to enter the key's passphrase, but doing so just displays the message again.

As a result of this, I cannot connect to the instance.

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Comment: [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23011136/659298).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Putty to connect to your server, here is the documentation instructing how to do this - 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html