# Accessing Digital Ocean Server

Tags: terminal, server, digital-ocean, ssh-keys

Trying to access my digital ocean server via a mac terminal.

```
ssh root@myipaddress
```

I'm then prompted for a password (I've never been prompted before, as I've left it blank intentionally.).  After 3 failed attempts I get:

```
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

I have also tried entering the ssh key for the server and get the same outcome.

I tried adding the key to my SSH-agent and get the following:

```
WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!
Permissions 0644 for '/Users/xxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa.xxx.pub' are too open
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others. 
This private key will be ignored.
```

I've tried contacting D.O. but have yet to hear back.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to access the server via:

```
ssh -i <keyfile> <user>@<hostname>
```

Seems like there was an issue with my machine defaulting to use my personal id_rsa file instead of the one that was created for this different server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the solution in:  [ssh "permissions are too open" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270734/ssh-permissions-are-too-open-error)?  Looks like the permissions on your private key are not restrictive enough.

Comment: Yes, I've changed to 600 but I still get the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!
Permissions 0644 for '/Users/xxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa.xxx.pub' are too open
```

Above messages shows some clarification. Try the below permissions.

```
# chown user:user ~/.ssh/*
# chmod 600 ~/.ssh/private_key
# chmod 644 ~/.ssh/public_key.pub
```

Try with these permissions. From the logs it seems to be unprotected permission/ownership.

Also try with `ssh -i ~/.ssh/private_key user@<IP> -vvv` for more insights :)