# Ansible in Docker conatiner failed to connect to Hetzner host via ssh

Tags: docker, ssh, ansible, windows-10

I'm pretty new to `Ansible` and I'm trying to run a playbook with `Docker` (Windows 10) but it fails to `ssh` into the Hetzner cloud.

I have created a `Makefile` to run Ansible in Docker

```
# Makefile
run_playbook:
    @docker run --rm \
        -v "C:/Users/myuser/.ssh/hetzner/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa" \
        -v "C:/Users/myuser/.ssh/hetzner/id_rsa.pub:/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" \
        -v $(CURDIR)/ansible.cfg:/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg \
        -v $(CURDIR):/myapp-ansible \
        -w /myapp-ansible \
        williamyeh/ansible:alpine3 \
        ansible-playbook -i staging site.yml -vvv
```

This is the `staging` inventory

```
[myapp]
<HETNER_SERVER_NAME> ansible_host=<HETZNER_SERVER_IP> ansible_user=root
```

and this is the `ansible.cfg`

```
# ansible.cfg
[defaults]
host_key_checking = false
roles_path = /myapp-ansible/roles

[privilege_escalation]
become = True
become_method = sudo
become_user = root
```

The problem is that when I run the `make run_playbook` command, I get the error `Failed to connect to the host via ssh`.

So I tried to manually connect from the docker container to see what happens and this is the result

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0755 for '/root/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "/root/.ssh/id_rsa": bad permissions
root@<HETZNER_SERVER_IP>'s password:
```

I tried to change the `id_rsa` permissions with `sudo chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa`, but it seems to have no effect

```
$ ls -l /root/.ssh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          2610 Aug 25 13:38 id_rsa
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           577 Aug 25 13:38 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           176 Aug 26 08:42 known_hosts
```

So I tried to change the `id_rsa` permissions directly in Windows as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1296024/windows-ssh-permissions-for-private-key-are-too-open), but I get the same result as before.

To be noted that in Windows I was able to ssh with Putty with the same private key without problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you consider coying the keys in your image and setting the perms at build time (if acceptable...)? An other option would be to mount your keys from host in an other location then copy to destination and change perms in your entrypoint script (to be created if it does not exist). I'm afraid fixing the ownership/perms problems between your windows host and linux container for a bind mount might end up in a real nightmare (if at all possible...).

Comment: After googling a lot I have found this https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-56-volume-mounting-ssh-keys-into-a-docker-container that suggests, as you, to set permissions on build time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After googling a lot I have found [this article](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-56-volume-mounting-ssh-keys-into-a-docker-container), so I changed the `run_playbook` as below:

```
run_playbook:
    @docker run -t --rm \
        -v "C:/Users/myuser/.ssh/hetzner/id_rsa:/tmp/.ssh/id_rsa" \
        -v "C:/Users/myuser/.ssh/hetzner/id_rsa.pub:/tmp/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" \
        -v $(CURDIR):/myapp-ansible \
        -w /myapp-ansible \
        williamyeh/ansible:alpine3 \
        /bin/sh -c "cp -R /tmp/.ssh /root/.ssh && chmod 700 /root/.ssh && chmod 644 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa"
        ansible-playbook -i staging site.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, **Windows 11** + **Docker** with ansible + volumes to **local id_rsa** + **docker compose**. After research, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270734/ssh-permissions-are-too-open).
I needed this answer:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  ansible:
    image: willhallonline/ansible:2.15-alpine-3.14
    volumes:
      - ${HOME}/.ssh/:/root/.ssh/
      - "./:/ansible/"
    command:
      - sh
      - -c
      - |
        chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
        ansible-playbook main.yml -i inventory.ini
```